# How to install specific package from beta release on stable

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I would like to try fingerprint packages from beta 18.10 to try if it works with my notebook fingerprint reader. What's the best way to try only some parts from beta release?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses a *snapshot* system - every six months updated packages are merged from Debian. These packages are often highly interdependent. This has many advantages for Debian and Ubuntu, but one drawback is that **packages from different releases of Ubuntu may be incompatible**.

**Many software maintainers provide PPAs** for safely testing pre-release software. This is, in fact, the original purpose of PPAs.

**If there is no PPA**, then the safest way to test pre-release packages without damaging your system is to try the *entire* Ubuntu pre-release, usually in a VM, LiveUSB, or separate partition.

**Folks who use pre-release software** are called *testers*, and are expected to be skilled in troubleshooting and filing bug reports. Pre-release software issues are generally considered off-topic here on AskUbuntu, since problems should be discussed in bug reports.

Only skilled users should attempt to install **different-release packages onto an existing system**. There are many possible complications from doing so. Cleanup may be easy...or very, very difficult.